# How to bubble sort structs in alphabetically way

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

I need to write a code where in a struct I register the license plate,model, brand, year and daily value of a car. After registering this data, I need to sort the entire struct based on the cars' license plate, and then display on the screen for the user. For example:

> Car 1
>
> car plate: IZA-2929
>      car model: GTR
>      car brand: Nissan
>      car year:  2016
>      daily value of car: 100
>
> Car 2
>
> car plate: BCC-1234
>      model car: Corolla
>      car brand: Toyota
>      car year: 2014
>      Car DailyValue:50
>
> Ordering...
>
> Car 2
>      car plate: BCC-1234
>      model car: Corolla
>      car brand: Toyota
>      car year: 2014
>      Car Daily Value:50
>
> Car 1
>      car plate: IZA-2929
>      car model: GTR
>      car brand: Nissan
>      car year: 2016
>      daily value of car: 100

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct carro
{
char placa[50];
char marca[50];
char modelo[50];
char ano[50];
char valordiaria[50];
};

int main()
{
struct carro car[5];
struct carro temp[5];


strcpy(car[0].placa, "IZA-2929");
strcpy(car[1].placa, "HJZ-1234");
strcpy(car[2].placa, "XCV-3478");
strcpy(car[3].placa, "BSD-8329");
strcpy(car[4].placa, "AHG-8332");

strcpy(car[0].marca, "Chevrolet");
strcpy(car[1].marca, "Volkswagen");
strcpy(car[2].marca, "Ferrari");
strcpy(car[3].marca, "Nissan");
strcpy(car[4].marca, "Ford");

strcpy(car[0].modelo, "Onix");
strcpy(car[1].modelo, "Golf");
strcpy(car[2].modelo, "Enzo");
strcpy(car[3].modelo, "GTR");
strcpy(car[4].modelo, "Ka");

strcpy(car[0].ano, "2013");
strcpy(car[1].ano, "2008");
strcpy(car[2].ano, "2004");
strcpy(car[3].ano, "2017");
strcpy(car[4].ano, "2015");

strcpy(car[0].valordiaria, "45");
strcpy(car[1].valordiaria, "60");
strcpy(car[2].valordiaria, "80");
strcpy(car[3].valordiaria, "200");
strcpy(car[4].valordiaria, "65");


int q=0;
int i,j,l,x;
```

> Here i show the struct as it is, not sorted yet.

```
for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
{
    printf("\nStruct desordenada:");
    printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[q].placa);
    printf("\nMarca: %s", car[q].marca);
    printf("\nModelo: %s", car[q].modelo);
    printf("\nAno: %s", car[q].ano);
    printf("\nValor da diaria: R$%s", car[q].valordiaria);
}
```

> Here is my Bubble Sort structure, that's what i am having trouble with

```
// :::BUBBLESORT::: //

for (j = 0; j < 5 - 1; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5 - 1; i++)
    {
        if ( strcmp(car[i].placa, car[i + 1].placa ) > 0)
        {
            temp = car[i];
            car[i] = car[i+1];
            car[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

> Here I show the all the struct ordered

```
for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
{
    printf("\nStruct Ordenana:");
    printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[q].placa);
    printf("\nMarca: %s", car[q].marca);
    printf("\nModelo: %s", car[q].modelo);
    printf("\nAno: %s", car[q].ano);
    printf("\nValor da diaria: R$%s", car[q].valordiaria);
}
```

}

> Here is the code itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct carro
{
    char placa[50];
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];
    char ano[50];
    char valordiaria[50];
};

int main()
{
    struct carro car[5];
    struct carro temp[5];

    strcpy(car[0].placa, "IZA-2929");
    strcpy(car[1].placa, "HJZ-1234");
    strcpy(car[2].placa, "XCV-3478");
    strcpy(car[3].placa, "BSD-8329");
    strcpy(car[4].placa, "AHG-8332");

    strcpy(car[0].marca, "Chevrolet");
    strcpy(car[1].marca, "Volkswagen");
    strcpy(car[2].marca, "Ferrari");
    strcpy(car[3].marca, "Nissan");
    strcpy(car[4].marca, "Ford");

    strcpy(car[0].modelo, "Onix");
    strcpy(car[1].modelo, "Golf");
    strcpy(car[2].modelo, "Enzo");
    strcpy(car[3].modelo, "GTR");
    strcpy(car[4].modelo, "Ka");

    strcpy(car[0].ano, "2013");
    strcpy(car[1].ano, "2008");
    strcpy(car[2].ano, "2004");
    strcpy(car[3].ano, "2017");
    strcpy(car[4].ano, "2015");

    strcpy(car[0].valordiaria, "45");
    strcpy(car[1].valordiaria, "60");
    strcpy(car[2].valordiaria, "80");
    strcpy(car[3].valordiaria, "200");
    strcpy(car[4].valordiaria, "65");


    int q=0;
    int i,j,x;

    for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
    {
        printf("\nStruct desordenada:");
        printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[q].placa);
        printf("\nMarca: %s", car[q].marca);
        printf("\nModelo: %s", car[q].modelo);
        printf("\nAno: %s", car[q].ano);
        printf("\nValor da diaria: R$%s", car[q].valordiaria);
    }



    // :::BUBBLESORT::: //

    for (j = 0; j < 5 - 1; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 5 - 1; i++)
        {
            if ( strcmp(car[q].placa, car[q + 1].placa ) > 0)
            {
                temp = car[q];
                car[q] = car[q+1];
                car[q+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
    {
        printf("\nStruct Ordenada:");
        printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[q].placa);
        printf("\nMarca: %s", car[q].marca);
        printf("\nModelo: %s", car[q].modelo);
        printf("\nAno: %s", car[q].ano);
        printf("\nValor da diaria: R$%s", car[q].valordiaria);
    }


}
```

Comment: What happens that you don't expect?

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something I can compile to help you find your problem. I'm not going to write the remainder of your code just to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a "typo" in your printing loops, you are iterating on variable **x** but are printing out on index **q** .

Comment: Changed it, thanks! But it didn't corrected it, i am getting 2 errors, the first in the "temp = car[q];" where it says "assignment to expression with  array type". The second one in the "car[q+1] = temp;", where says "incompatible types when assingment to type 'struct carro' from type 'struct carro*'.